# Extrapolate the Research & Development

Tags: stocks, research

[image: GM operating expenses & income]

From [General Motors](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/GM/income-statement) income statement on Seeking Alpha, we can see in the *Operating Expenses and Income* that we have the *Selling General & Admin Expenses*. Why can't we see the *Research and Development*? Is there a way to extrapolate them? The thing is I am trying to find the % of R&D in relation to the Gross Margin, but I have no way to find the R&D.

Comment: What is the name of the stock?

Comment: @Flux The stock is GM (https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/GM/income-statement)

Comment: Did you check GM's 2021 Form 10-K filing?

Comment: @Flux Seeking Alpha already fetched the information from the 10-K filings.

Comment: @J.Doe Did you check whether the 10-K shows the amount/percent of R&D spending in case they _didn't_ fetch that particular piece of information?

Comment: I just did, but I did not find the information.

Comment: @J.Doe Could you provide a link to the Form 10-K you looked at? I found the information in part 1, item 1 of the 2021 Form 10-K by searching for the word "research".